# display multiple table

Tags: jsp

I have two radio buttons  with  values itemwise and supplierwise. If I select itemwise then i should display one table and if i select supplierwise then i should display another table. My coding is displaying the tables correctly but the tables are not displayed in same position. To display them in same position what should i do? My code is given below-----

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    function hideTable()
        {

            document.getElementById('item_table').style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById('supplier_table').style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        function showItemTable()
        {
            if(document.getElementById("item_selection").checked==true)
            {
                document.getElementById('supplier_table').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('item_table').style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function showSupplierTable()
        {
            if(document.getElementById("supplier_selection").checked==true)
            {
                document.getElementById('item_table').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('supplier_table').style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:hideTable()">
    <form name = "form1" method ="post" action="">
        <table border="1"  align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Report Required</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="item_selection" id="item_selection" onclick="showItemTable()">Item Wise</td>                
                        <td><input type="radio" name="item_selection" id="supplier_selection" onclick="showSupplierTable()">Supplier Wise</td>    
                    </tr>
                </table>

        <table border="1" bgColor="#9999CC" align="center" id="item_table">
                        <tr>
                            <td  colspan="2">Item Type</td>
                            <td colspan="2"><%=item_typeddListStr%></td>
                        </tr>         
                        <tr>
                            <td  colspan="2">Item Category</td>
                            <td colspan="2"><%=item_categoryddListStr%></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td  colspan="2">Item Name</td>
                            <td colspan="2" id='item_code'>  
                                <select name='item_code' >  
                                    <option value='-1'></option>  
                                </select>  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>From Date</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="indent_date" id="issue_date_first"  size="12"/></td>
                            <td>To Date</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="indent_date" id="issue_date_second"  size="12"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Get Records" onclick="return validate()"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Generate Report" onclick="return validate()"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Clear Form"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Back"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

            <table border="1" bgColor="#9999CC" align="center" id="supplier_table">
                        <tr>
                            <td  colspan="2">Supplier Name</td>
                            <td colspan="2"><%=supplier_codeddListStr%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Get Records" onclick="return validate()"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Generate Report" onclick="return validate()"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Clear Form"></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="Back"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *style.display* instead of *style.visibility*

```
document.getElementById('supplier_table').style.display = "none";
// ...
document.getElementById('supplier_table').style.display= "block";
```

I'd also suggest using [jQuery](https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://jquery.com/&ei=R81nUZz8HM_Lsgb0u4HoBw&usg=AFQjCNFA7CZ5sWRDhHPuipmhL7zVksjC2A&sig2=LG-jDZNsVXoZxEwACZmdSQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.Yms) for simplifying the JS code. For example, you could

```
function swapTables() {
    $("#supplier_table").toggle();
    $("#item_table").toggle();
}
```

and that's it.

Also, as the question is more related to HTML/CSS than JSP could you please add those tags? just for clarity...

Comment: @user1407310 Would you mind if I asked you to _accept_ the answer then?